# Query to fetch summarized information from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have below query to fetch some information from the database.

```
select a.PIPE_SYS, c.WELD_TYPE, c.RT, sum(a.W_C) welded, 
count(d.RT_CMP_DATE) Tested, count(a.RT_STATUS) Accepted
from Weld_master a, Weld_names b, NDT_PER_CATEGORY_ c, Nd_Test d 
where a.WELD_NAME = b.WELD_NAME and b.TYPE = c.WELD_TYPE and a.NDT_CATEGORY = 
c.CATEGORY  and a.project_no = d.proj_no and a.dwg_no = d.dwg_no and 
a.Spool_No = d.Spool_No and a.weld_no = d.weld_no group by a.PIPE_SYS, c.rt, 
c.WELD_TYPE;
```

Above gives me the correct result as I expect except for **Accepted** field. Since, the data in my database is saved in a way that by default `RT_STATUS` field is set to a certain value (non null) and when `RT status` of a weld is Accepted or Rejected then `RT_STATUS` field is updated with relevant value in database.

So, in above query, how can I get count of Accepted and Rejected `RT_STATUS` field.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  In addition, use meaningful table aliases.  Aliases such as "a", "b", and "c" just make the query harder to understand.

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/

Comment: Please show sample data, expected results and actual results. Please format your SQL for readability.

Comment: without seeing the source data and a sample of expected output it's very difficult to answer the question. Also your SQL is barely readable. Please format it to be easier to read. If you write all your code like that it must be hard to review, and hard to comprehend when you come to alter it later.

Comment: `when RT status of a weld is Accepted/Rejected then RT_Status is field is updated with relevant value.` Can you please explain this clearly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

```
sum(case when a.RT_STATUS = 'Accepted' then 1 else 0 end) AS AcceptedCount,
sum(case when a.RT_STATUS = 'Rejected' then 1 else 0 end) AS RejectedCount
```

Comment: exactly what I needed.. Cheers